# browserHistory.push not working in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am very new to reactJs. I am trying to change the tab on click of button. For this I am using `browserHistory`.

Problem here is `url` is getting changed but component is not getting rendered.
Couldn't understand this.

```
browserHistory.push("/personalInfo");
```

This is how I am trying to change the tab.
Url is getting changed to `http://localhost:3000/personalInfo`. But component is not rendered, when I refresh the browser, it's getting changed.

Comment: Why are you not using link for the same? Link is like anchor tag. https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

Comment: which version of `react-router` are using? `browserHistory` was removed in the latest `react-router` (v.4), so I am guessing it is an old version. is it a limitation of your project that you are not using the latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `withRouter`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

class MyComponent extends Component {

  sampleFunction() {
    this.props.history.push("/personalInfo");
  }

}
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```